# Mass tag update on bookmarks

Tags: delicious, delicious-tags

My Delicious account has a great many bookmarks tagged "Bookmarks" - this would have happened when I imported my browser bookmarks into the service. The tag is redundant, and I've worked on eliminating its use. It's a matter of a few clicks to edit a single bookmark and remove the tag; the problem is that I have over 700 bookmarks with the "Bookmarks" tag. Ugh.

Is there any easy or automated way to mass edit bookmark tags, or even to remove a particular tag altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log into http://www.delicious.com

At the top there should be `Home Bookmarks People Tags`, click on `Tags`, `My Tags`

On the right hand side, underneath the search bar, highlighted in blue click on `Delete Tags`

Choose a tag from the dropdown.  This will remove that tag from your bookmarks, and delete the tag.

---

To just remove the tag from certain bookmarks without deleting it, select `Bookmarks` at the top.

On the right hand side under the search bar, select `Bulk Edit`.  Select the bookmarks you wish to edit and go to `Remove Tag` under the thick blue line.